# Instagram followers' page URL

Tags: instagram

If I'm logged into my Instagram account on my computer, is there a URL I can access to view a list of the people who follow me? Like the one on the mobile app?

Answer (score 1):

There's no way to do this by using Instagram's webapp, but if you use a third party webclient like [Iconosquare](http://iconosquare.com/), [following this link](http://iconosquare.com/viewer.php#/myFollowers/) takes you to your followers page after you sign in using Instagram credentials.